# Rudimentary File Explorer Using Dialog Boxes with FSELECT: Bash

Tags: bash, dialog

I'm trying to do a rudimentary file explorer, as the title says. What I want to do is present the user with a dialog box that allows them to select a file, in this case, a .rar file, but I want them to be able to select the directory where they put the files. Each of them tend to name the directories in which the put these .rar files in a different way, so that's why I want to allow them to navigate between directories using the dialog box.

So far I've come up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# select a file with a dialog box
# save it in FILE

# If the user picks another directory, show the content of the new directory
# The script must keep iterating between directories until the correct files
# are chosen. This must be done recursively.

FILE=$(dialog --clear --title "File Viewer" --stdout \
       --title "Select a file"\
       --fselect /recursos/ 14 58)

# Here I try to keep iterating between directories
while [ -d "$FILE" ]
do
  # If the user picks a directory
  if [ -d "$FILE" ]
  then       
    cd "$FILE"  # Change path to that directory
    DIR=$PWD    # Save the new path
    FILE=""     # Clear the selection
    dialog --clear   # Destroy previous dialog box
  else
    echo "Error."
    exit -1
  fi

  # Show a new dialog and allow a new selection
  FILE=$(dialog --clear --title "File Viewer" --stdout \
         --title "Select a file"\
         --fselect "$DIR" 14 58)
         echo "Value of $FILE inside the while"
         exit -1   # Exit
done

# Print the name of the file
echo $FILE
```

I use the forced exit inside the while loop, because I want to test the values of $FILE, anyways, it's not working as intended. I haven't found examples of how to iterate between directories. I can't use Zenity or any other visual UIs as the server I'm working on has no Internet and I can't download new features or anything to the OS. Also, I can't use --dselect as an option with the Dialog, I don't know why, so what you see it's what I can work with.

Any idea on how this can be done?

**Edit:**

Ok, here's what I wanna do. Sometimes, the guys at my work receive some files, they're are compressed as .rar files. They put these files in a folder and then they name the directory after the date they arrive, let's say JUN30 or something. But they name the folders as they please, and they often do, they don't follow any rules in naming these directories.

I want to make a script that allows them to navigate to the folder where they put these compressed files, select the files, and once they press OK, the program will execute a series of steps that are done after those files are uncompressed.

Allowing the users to type in the folder where they put the compressed files doesn't seem to be viable, since working visually would be easier. You know, I don't want the users to be able to mess around too much. It's necessary to do this, since uncompressing the files is only the first step of many, and I was assigned with automating a lot of tasks.

**Edit:**

I changed my code to work a bit differently since the old way wasn't doing what I wanted, here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

function fileChooser(){
  local __DIR=$1
  local __RESULT=$(dialog --clear --title "Choose Directory" --stdout \
                   --title "Choose File"\
                   --fselect $__DIR 14 58)

  echo $__RESULT
}

RESULT=$( fileChooser /recursos/ )

while [ -d "$RESULT" ]
do
  RESULT=$( fileChooser "$RESULT/" )
done

# Print selection
echo $RESULT
```

Any suggestions on what I should improve to make my code as fail safe as possible? The intention is that the users should be able to execute a bunch of automated tasks without much intervention on their part other than picking the directory with the files.

Comment: What isn't working as intended? What is (or isn't) happening? What is (or isn't) working? What are the values of the variables as you go along? What do you see if you add `set -x` to the top of the script?

Comment: @EtanReisner For example, I want to choose a directory, and when I do, I want that the dialog shows the files inside that directory, but the program ends whenever I press enter or OK, I have to manually press space bar to select something first, and even if I press the space bar to choose a directory, the program picks that directory and ends, and I want to keep inside the dialog and be able to change directories inside the dialog box, and only exit when I pick a file.

Comment: If you are expecting to stay inside the `dialog` window until you have selected a file then why does your script assume that `dialog` will return a directory and that you will need to run it again? Also navigating the `dialog` fselect window is sort of strange it seems. It auto-updates the lists at the top as you type out directory names. So if you use space to select a directory and then type `/` the views will change.

Comment: @EtanReisner See my edit for comments on what the program's intention is.

Comment: That's a nice explanation and may be helpful for suggestions other than `dialog` but doesn't address my comments or how `dialog` seems to work. You seem to expect it to work differently then it does. Or rather you seem to have written the script expecting people to navigate around `dialog` badly (which is fine). You still haven't explained what isn't working though.

Comment: @EtanReisner well...it is working in some way. But not the way I want. The problem is, that if I pick a directory from the file selection box, I want to navigate to that directory, and show what's inside that directory from within the dialog box. What's happening instead is that the dialog exits as soon as I pick something, directory or file. It is working, but I don't want it to exit as soon as I pick a directory.

Comment: That's because you are using `dialog` "incorrectly" as I said. Don't hit `<enter>`. Hit `<space>` and then type `/` and the views will update. If you hit enter you finish the selection and get it in the output (and your loop looks like it should handle that correctly though I haven't tried it and I'm not sure what the `--clear` is there for).

Comment: @EtanReisner what other options do I have for a crude file explorer? I'm at a lost here. See my second edit for what I have come up with so far. It is doing what I wanted it to do. But I think it can be improved. If you press space bar and choose a directory, and then press ENTER or OK, now it shows what's in the directory you choose instead of exiting the program. Now it only exits if you select a file.

Comment: Learn to use `dialog --fselect` the way it expects to be used (and teach your users about it (but plan for failure with your loop) or use some other method (I don't know of any offhand). `dialog --fselect` *can* be used the way you want you just need to navigate it the way it expects to be used.

Comment: **Don't** hit enter until you've selected the file. Hit `<space>` then **type** a `/` and the view will update and you can navigate another level, etc.

Comment: HI @AnubisLockward, thanks a lot for your script. I've modified it a bit and [put it up on github](https://github.com/tpo/little_shell_scripts/blob/master/file_chooser).

Comment: @TomášPospíšek wow man, thanks a lot. I don't really know how to feel about this. I just did this script to see if it could be done. I'm glad you found it useful and thanks a lot for the mention.